# http get and post Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, post

Hello here's my json "names" :

```
[
    {
        "file": "file1.zip",
        "date": "12-03-2016",
    },
    {
        "file": "file2.zip",
        "date": "24-06-2016",
    },
    {
        "file": "file3.zip",
        "date": "02-12-2016",
    }]
```

My javascript file:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.service('service', function($http, $q){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get('newapi.json').then(function(data){
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });

        this.getNames = function(){
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    });
    app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, service){
        var promise = service.getNames();
        promise.then(function(data){
            $scope.names = data.data;
            $scope.namesplit = $scope.names;
            $scope.namesplit.map(function(item) {
                item.time = new Date(item.date * 1000);
            });
            console.log($scope.namesplit);
        });
        });
```

and HTML :

```
<tr ng-repeat="name in names">
   <td>{{name.file}}</td>
   <td>{{name.date}}</td>
   <td><button>POST</button></td>
</tr>
```

Well i have a table and what i need is when i click on button, the "file" post to serwer. I know i must use $http.post but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: You want to upload a file (for example file1.zip) on a server?

Comment: @conventi yes, after click button.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post

Answer (score 0):

So Simple
Html

```
<button ng-click="post()">Click Me</button>
```

Controller

```
    $scope.post=function(){
$http.post(URL HERE, data-here, {    
 })
  .then(function onSuccess(response) {
    // Handle success
    var data = response.data;
    var status = response.status;
    var statusText = response.statusText;
    var headers = response.headers;
    var config = response.config;
    ...
  }).
  catch(function onError(response) {
    // Handle error
    var data = response.data;
    var status = response.status;
    var statusText = response.statusText;
    var headers = response.headers;
    var config = response.config;
    ...
  });
  }
```

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't see the word file.

Comment: I am commenting here because I didn't have enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

For upload a file using `$http.post()` function you have to set some additional parameters like `headers` and and `transformRequest`.

Here a simple example:

```
$scope.postToServer = function(){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file); 
    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
    .success(function(){
    })
    .error(function(){
    });
}
```

*Note: in this example the file var is the content of the file located on client file system and the uploadUrl is the URL of your service that handle the request.*